# WebRTC getUserMedia deviceId constraint is not supported

Tags: google-chrome, getusermedia, deviceid

I am trying to get device Id from user by using WebRTC API `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`. But the function throws an `OverconstrainedError` which has `constraint` property inside says `deviceId`. This means something was wrong with the `deviceId`.

However, I don't see any reason for browser to can't get device ID. Actually I haven't experienced this issue before.

Do you have any idea what would be the reason? Would it be because of the camera or is it all about the browser?

Comment: Which chrome version are you working on?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are passing as contraints to the gUM but if you look at this code on github ( https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/ ), it provides a good example of toggling various media inputs and you can see in the source (or step through the code in the debugger) what the constraints are set to and how they get the deviceId - note this is not my code but is part of the webRTC samples.